# SQL select any row that data in column zipcode matches data within an array?

Tags: php, sql, database, geolocation

OK so question is I have am doing a custom geolocation on the site 702web.com/tutors

Use a inner page for searching as the home page search is not done.

I have it setup to where is user doesnt enter a zipcode and subject is any it will display all tutors, also have it to where is no zipcode is entered and they select a subject then all tutors that teach that subject will be displayed, I also have it to where is a zipcode is enter and user selects any then any tutor in that zipcode gets displayed, the forth and final is if user enters zipcode and subject then all tutors that teach that subject and in that zip code get displayed.

Doing it that way is easy, but to make it slightly more complicated for the third and forth I have it selecting all zipcodes that are in a 40 mile radius of the user entered zip code (using a table with all zip codes and latitude and longitudes). The finding all the zip codes within that radius is working.

**My question is this** 
How to a query that database using an array? since all the zip codes in that radius are put in an array how can I tell use the SELECT statement to "SELECT * FROM wp_testimonials WHERE postcode = '".$THIS IS MY ARRAY??"' AND find_in_set( '".$_REQUEST['subject']."', subject )"

**CODE OF THE RESULTS PAGE**

```
<?php
        if(isset($_REQUEST['send']) OR !empty($_REQUEST['zipcode'])) {
            if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{5}$/', $_REQUEST['zipcode'])) {

                    include('search_page.php');

            }
            else {

        //connect to db server; select database
                $link = mysql_connect('t0tors102938.db.7131821.hostedresource.com', 't0tors102938', 'aL8#Jfo89!') or die('Cannot connect to database server');
                mysql_select_db('t0tors102938') or die('Cannot select database');

                //query for coordinates of provided ZIP Code
                if(!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_us_zipcodes WHERE zip_code = '$_REQUEST[zipcode]'")) {
                    echo "<p><strong>There was a database error attempting to retrieve your ZIP Code.</strong> Please try again.</p>\n";
                }
                else {
                    if(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
                        echo "<p><strong>No database match for provided ZIP Code.</strong> Please enter a new ZIP Code.</p>\n"; 
                    }
                    else {
                        //if found, set variables
                        $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
                        $lat1 = $row['latitude'];
                        $lon1 = $row['longitude'];
                        $d = 40;
                        $r = 3959;

                        //compute max and min latitudes / longitudes for search square
                        $latN = rad2deg(asin(sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos($d / $r) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad(0))));
                        $latS = rad2deg(asin(sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos($d / $r) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad(180))));
                        $lonE = rad2deg(deg2rad($lon1) + atan2(sin(deg2rad(90)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad($lat1)), cos($d / $r) - sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($latN))));
                        $lonW = rad2deg(deg2rad($lon1) + atan2(sin(deg2rad(270)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad($lat1)), cos($d / $r) - sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($latN))));



                        //find all coordinates within the search square's area
                        //exclude the starting point and any empty city values
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_us_zipcodes WHERE (latitude <= $latN AND latitude >= $latS AND longitude <= $lonE AND longitude >= $lonW) AND city != '' ORDER BY state, city, latitude, longitude";
                        if(!$rs = mysql_query($query)) {
                            echo "<p><strong>There was an error selecting nearby ZIP Codes from the database.</strong></p>\n";
                        }
                        elseif(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
                            echo "<p><strong>No nearby ZIP Codes located within the distance specified.</strong> Please try a different distance.</p>\n";                               
                        }
                        else {
                            //output all matches to screen
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
                                foreach($row['zip_code'] as $rows) {
                                    $queryzipcodes[] = $rows;

                                }
                            }
                            $sqlzip = implode(',',$queryzipcodes);

                            echo "$queryzipcodes";
                            //echo 'ok';

                                if($_REQUEST['subject']!='' && $_REQUEST['zipcode']!='')
            {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM wp_testimonials WHERE postcode IN ($sqlzip) AND find_in_set( '".$_REQUEST['subject']."', subject )";
            }elseif($_REQUEST['subject']!='') {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM wp_testimonials WHERE find_in_set( '".$_REQUEST['subject']."', subject )";
            }
            elseif($_REQUEST['zipcode']!='') {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM wp_testimonials WHERE postcode = '".$_REQUEST['zipcode']."'";
            }
            else
            {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM wp_testimonials";
            }
        //echo $sql;

        $tutors = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

                $count = 0;

                print('<br>');
                foreach ($tutors as $tutor)
                {
                    $odd = $count%2;
                   if ($odd == 1)
                   {
                        $bgcolor='#fafafa';
                   }elseif ($odd == 0)
                   {
                        $bgcolor='#f0f0f0';
                   }
                     $sql3="SELECT sfimgurl FROM wp_testimonials WHERE testid='".$tutor->testid."'";
                     $res3=mysql_query($sql3);
                     $data3=mysql_fetch_assoc($res3);

                     $blogurl = get_bloginfo('wpurl');
                     $imgsrc =  '/wp-content/uploads/';
                     $tutorimg =  $data3['sfimgurl'];

                     print('<table width="100%" style="border-radius: 10px;" bgcolor="'.$bgcolor.'">');

                     print('<tr height="145px"><td width="110px" style="padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px; vertical-align: top; "><div style="height:145px; overflow:hidden; float: left; padding-right: 10px; border: dotted; border-width: 0 1px 0 0"><img src="'.$blogurl.'' .$imgsrc.'' .$tutorimg.'" width="100" height="145" />');

                     print('</div></td>');
                     print('<td valign="top" width="150px" style="float:left; padding-left: 5px; padding-top:5px;"><div style="float: left; font-size:12px;"><strong>TUTOR:<br><a href="?page_id=175&tid=' .$tutor->testid. '">'.$tutor->clientname.'</a><br></strong><br>');


                $subj=$tutor->subject;
                $arrr_subject=explode(',', $subj);
                for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
                //$i<count($arrr_subject)
                    $sql2="select * from wp_tutorcat WHERE subid='".$arrr_subject[$i]."'";
                    $res2=mysql_query($sql2);
                    $data2=mysql_fetch_assoc($res2);
                    $subject2 = (strlen($data2['subject']) > 20) ? substr($data2['subject'],0,17).'...' : $data2['subject'];
                    echo $subject2.'<br>';

                }


                     //print('<br> '.$tutor->text_full.'<br/><br/>');
                     print('<br><strong>Zip Code: '.$tutor->postcode.'</strong></div></td>');


                 print('<td width="350px" style="padding-left:10px; padding-top: 5px; vertical-align: top; border: dotted; border-width: 0 0 0 1px;"><div style="float: left; font-size: 12px; position: relative; padding-right: 5px; ">');
                $idnum=$tutor->testid;
//$bio=$data['text_full'];
$sql3="SELECT text_full FROM wp_testimonials WHERE testid='".$idnum."'";
$res3=mysql_query($sql3);
$data3=mysql_fetch_assoc($res3);
$ses = "'s";
$bio = (strlen($data3['text_full']) > 103) ? substr($data3['text_full'],0,100).'...' : $data3['text_full'];
echo '<strong>BIO:</strong>


<br>'.$bio.'<br></div>';


                print('<div align="center"><p style="text-align: center;"><span class="bk-button-wrapper"><a href="?page_id=175&tid=' .$tutor->testid. '" target="_self" class="bk-button red center rounded small" style="margin-top: 15px;">View '.$tutor->clientname.''. $ses . ' Profile</a></span></p></div>');

                print('</td></tr></table>');



                     $count++;


                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


               ?>
```

Comment: new code and select statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys I figured it out.

To figure this out from start to finish took me a total of about 12 hours working time.

**CODE FOR DISPLAY RESULTS AND AS FORM ACTION FOR HOME PAGE**

```
<?php
    /*
        Template Name: Tutor Locator Template
    */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary">
 <div class="small-search-tutor">

<div class="small-search-tutor-box">

 <?php
 include('post_search.php');
 ?>

</div>
</div>

        <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

<br />

<?php

// Create page variables
$r = 50;
$z = NULL;
$stores = NULL;
$Errors = NULL;

// Establish DB connection
$dbc = mysql_connect ('t0tors102938.db.7131821.hostedresource.com', 't0tors102938', 'aL8#Jfo89!');
mysql_select_db ('t0tors102938', $dbc);

// Declare page functions
function Dist ($lat_A, $long_A, $lat_B, $long_B) {

  $distance = sin(deg2rad($lat_A))
  * sin(deg2rad($lat_B))
  + cos(deg2rad($lat_A))
  * cos(deg2rad($lat_B))
  * cos(deg2rad($long_A - $long_B));

$distance = (rad2deg(acos($distance))) * 69.09;
return $distance;

}

### Handle form if submitted
if (isset ($_REQUEST['send']) OR !empty($_REQUEST['zipcode'])) {

// Validate Zip code field
 if (!empty ($_REQUEST['zipcode']) && is_numeric ($_REQUEST['zipcode'])) {

$z = (int)$_REQUEST['zipcode'];

// Verify zip code exists
 $query = "SELECT lat, lon FROM zip_codes WHERE zip = '$z'";
 $result = mysql_query ($query);

 if (mysql_num_rows ($result) == 1) {
  $zip = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result);
 } else {
  $Errors = '<p>The zip code you entered was not found!</p>';
}

 }elseif (empty ($_REQUEST['zipcode'])){
$query = "SELECT lat, lon FROM zip_codes";
  $result = mysql_query ($query);

 if (mysql_num_rows ($result) == 1) {
  $zip = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result);
 } else {
  $Errors = '<p>The zip code you entered was not found!</p>';
}

}



// Proceed if no errors were found


// Retrieve coordinates of the stores
$tutors = array();
$r = 50;
if(empty($_REQUEST['zipcode']) && $_REQUEST['subject']!='Any'){

$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_testimonials WHERE find_in_set( '".$_REQUEST['subject']."', subject )";  
}

 elseif($_REQUEST['subject']!='Any'){
$query = "SELECT testid, clientname, phone, email, subject, text_full, hourly_rate, postcode, lat, lon
FROM wp_testimonials
INNER JOIN zip_codes
ON wp_testimonials.postcode = zip_codes.zip
AND find_in_set( '".$_REQUEST['subject']."', subject )";
}

 elseif(empty($_REQUEST['zipcode']) && $_REQUEST['subject']='Any'){
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_testimonials";   
}

 elseif(!empty($_REQUEST['zipcode']) && $_REQUEST['subject']='Any'){
$query = "SELECT testid, clientname, phone, email, subject, text_full, hourly_rate, postcode, lat, lon
FROM wp_testimonials
INNER JOIN zip_codes
ON wp_testimonials.postcode = zip_codes.zip";   
}

$result = mysql_query ($query);

// Go through and check all stores
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) {

  // Separate closest stores
  $distance = Dist ($row['lat'], $row['lon'], $zip['lat'], $zip['lon']);

  // Check if store is in radius
  if ($distance <= $r) {

    $tutors[] = array (
      'testid'      => $row['testid'],
      'clientname'      => $row['clientname'],
      'email'   => $row['email'],
      'subject'      => $row['subject'],
      'postcode'    => $row['postcode'],
      'text_full'     => $row['text_full'],
      'phone'     => $row['phone'],
      'hourly_rate'     => $row['hourly_rate']
     );

   }

  }

 } else {
  $Errors = ($Errors) ? $Errors : '<p>Errors were found please try again!</p>';
}


?>


<?php

if (isset ($tutors)) {

  if (!empty ($tutors)) {
$count = 0;
   //echo '<p><strong>' . count ($tutors) . ' results were found.</strong></p>';
    foreach ($tutors as $value) {
                $odd = $count%2;
                   if ($odd == 1)
                   {
                        $bgcolor='#fafafa';
                   }elseif ($odd == 0)
                   {
                        $bgcolor='#f0f0f0';
                   }    
    $sql3="SELECT sfimgurl FROM wp_testimonials WHERE testid='".$value['testid']."'";
                     $res3=mysql_query($sql3);
                     $data3=mysql_fetch_assoc($res3);

                     $blogurl = get_bloginfo('wpurl');
                     $imgsrc =  '/wp-content/uploads/';
                     $tutorimg =  $data3['sfimgurl'];


echo '<table width="100%" style="border-radius: 10px;" bgcolor="'.$bgcolor.'">';                 
echo '<tr height="145px"><td width="110px" style="padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px; vertical-align: top; "><div style="height:145px; overflow:hidden; float: left; padding-right: 10px; border: dotted; border-width: 0 1px 0 0"><img src="'.$blogurl.'' .$imgsrc.'' .$tutorimg.'" width="100" height="145" /><div></td>';       

echo '<td valign="top" width="150px" style="float:left; padding-left: 5px; padding-top:5px;"><div style="float: left; font-size:12px;"><strong>TUTOR:<br><a href="?page_id=175&tid=' .$value['testid']. '">'.$value['clientname'].'</a><br></strong><br>';

$arrr_subject = array();
                $arrr_subject=explode(',', $value['subject']);
                for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
                    $sql2="SELECT * FROM wp_tutorcat WHERE subid='".$arrr_subject[$i]."'";
                    $results2=mysql_query($sql2);
                    $row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($results2);
                    $subject2 = (strlen($row2['subject']) > 20) ? substr($row2['subject'],0,17).'...' : $row2['subject'];

                if($subject2!=''){
                echo $subject2.'<br>';  
                }else{
                //do nothing
                }
                }

    // echo '<br />Hourly Rate: ' . $value['hourly_rate'] . '<br />';
     echo '<br><strong>Zip Code: '.$value['postcode'].'</strong></div></td>';           
    echo '<td width="350px" style="padding-left:10px; padding-top: 5px; vertical-align: top; border: dotted; border-width: 0 0 0 1px;"><div style="float: left; font-size: 12px; position: relative; padding-right: 5px; ">';
  $ses = "'s";
  $bio = (strlen($value['text_full']) > 103) ? substr($value['text_full'],0,100).'...' : $value['text_full'];


  echo '<strong>BIO:</strong><br>'.$bio.'<br></div>';


  echo '<div align="center"><p style="text-align: center;"><span class="bk-button-wrapper"><a href="?page_id=175&tid=' .$value['testid']. '" target="_self" class="bk-button red center rounded small" style="margin-top: 15px;">View '.$value['clientname'].''. $ses . ' Profile</a></span></p></div>';



  echo '</td></tr></table>';
    $count++;
 }

  } else {
echo '<p><strong>No results found</strong></p>';
  }



}

?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>





        </div><!-- #content -->

    </div><!-- #primary -->



<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

**CODE FOR SEARCH BAR ON ALL INNER PAGES**

```
<?php 
//print_r($_REQUEST);
if($_REQUEST['send']=='send')
{
if($_REQUEST['subject']!='Any' AND empty($_REQUEST['zipcode'])){
header("Location:?page_id=275&subject=".$_REQUEST['subject']);  
}
elseif ($_REQUEST['subject']=='Any' AND !empty($_REQUEST['zipcode'])){
header("Location:?page_id=410&zipcode=".$_REQUEST['zipcode']."&subject=".$_REQUEST['subject']); 
}
elseif (empty($_REQUEST['zipcode'])){
header("Location:?page_id=275&subject=");
}
else{
header("Location:?page_id=410&zipcode=".$_REQUEST['zipcode']."&subject=".$_REQUEST['subject']);
}
}
?>

 <form method="post" action="">
 <div style="display:inline-block; width:60px; font-size:12px; vertical-align:top; padding-top:7px;">ZIP
 <input type="text" id="zip" name="zipcode" style="width:100px; margin-top:-10px;"/>
 </div>
 <div style="display:inline-block; width:180px; padding-left:50px; vertical-align:top; padding-top:7px; font-size:12px;">SUBJECT:
 <select name="subject" style="width:180px;">
    <option value="Any">Any</option>
    <?php
$sql="select * from wp_tutorcat";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
   $rr="select * FROM wp_testimonials WHERE find_in_set( '".$data['subid']."', `subject` )";
   $ff=mysql_query($rr);
   $num=mysql_num_rows($ff);
   if($num>0)
   {
?>
<option value="<?=$data['subid']?>" <?php if(in_array($data['subid'],$arrr)) echo 'selected'?>><?=$data['subject']?></option>

<?php
}
}
?>

</select>




  </div>

  <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; padding-top:23px; ">
    <input type="hidden" value="send" name="send" />
    <input type="submit" name="search"  value="search"/>

  </div>

</form>
```

**TUTORS DATABASE TABLE SQL**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.11.11.3
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 0.0.0.0
-- Generation Time: Mar 22, 2013 at 02:58 PM
-- Server version: 5.0.96
-- PHP Version: 5.1.6

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

--
-- Database: `t0tor******`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_testimonials`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_testimonials`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_testimonials` (
  `testid` int(15) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `clientname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(999) NOT NULL,
  `text_full` varchar(999) NOT NULL,
  `hourly_rate` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `package_discount` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `group_discount` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sfimgurl` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `storder` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `featured` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`testid`),
  KEY `postal` (`postcode`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_testimonials`
--

INSERT INTO `wp_testimonials` VALUES(8, 'Jill Mohlman', '', 'Jill@gmail.com', '25,28,34,39,51,66,104', 'Highest Degree: Bachelors in education\r\nCollege:  Brigham Young\r\nYears as a Teacher:  7\r\nYears as a Tutor: 4', '13', '', '', 'Jill-Mohlman.jpg', '79912', 0, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO `wp_testimonials` VALUES(9, 'Heather Severson', '', '', '33,62,89,104,105,107', 'Highest Degree:  Master of Music\r\nCollege:  Brigham Young\r\nYears as a Teacher:  15\r\n\r\nBio:\r\nWith a Masters Degree in Music and a classically trained violinist, Heather believes that each student requires an individual approach to learning.  Heather focuses on each students strengths and weaknesses, then alters her teaching methods to meet a students needs accordingly.  \r\nHighest Degree:  Master of Music', '13', '', '', 'Heather-Seaverson.jpg', '84054', 0, 'No');
INSERT INTO `wp_testimonials` VALUES(10, 'Floyd Fitzgibbons', '', '', '103', 'Name:  Floyd Fitzgibbons\r\nHighest Degree: Certified Insurance Counselor\r\nCollege:  UNLV\r\nYears as a Teacher:  8+\r\nYears as a Tutor: 5+', '18', '', '', 'Floyd-Fitzgibbons.jpg', '89149', 0, 'No');
INSERT INTO `wp_testimonials` VALUES(12, 'Ryan Fitzgibbons', '', '', '40,67', 'An accomplished teacher and tutor, Ryan ranked as one of the highest rated Kaplan Instructors in the nation for SAT and ACT score improvement. His students have gone to every Ivy League school. Many still keep in contact to report their academic successes, even years after the fact. He has received tremendous reviews from students and parents alike for his friendly and patient attitude, and ability to get results.\r\n\r\n-Member: Mensa High IQ Society - \r\n\r\nScored in 99th percentile on SAT & ACT - \r\n\r\nEagle Scout - Nationally ranked Kaplan SAT & ACT Specialist - \r\n\r\n\\"Ryan cares more than any teacher I\\''ve ever met. He loses more sleep anxiously awaiting his students\\'' test results than they do!\\"', '39', '', '', 'Ryan-Fitzgibbons-200x300.jpg', '89129', 0, 'No');
INSERT INTO `wp_testimonials` VALUES(13, 'Royce Seaverson', '', '', '21,23,28,31,34,37,38,41,42,48,49,66,76,77,82,89,105', 'Highest Degree: Masters\r\nCollege:  BYU', '15', '', '', 'Royce-Seaverson.jpg', '84054', 0, 'No');
INSERT INTO `wp_testimonials` VALUES(14, 'Billy Bob', '', '', '103,104', '', '', '', '', '2012/11/how-it-works-191x300.jpg', '79912', 0, '');
INSERT INTO `wp_testimonials` VALUES(16, 'Billy Joel', '702-539-0540', 'nicholas@702web.com', '24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48', 'I am a great Tutor', '11', '', '', 'footer-purchasing.jpg', '89141', 0, 'Yes');
```

**PARTIAL SQL FOR ZIP CODE LIST**

Get full list here http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/zip-code-database/

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.11.11.3
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 
-- Generation Time: Mar 22, 2013 at 04:39 PM
-- Server version: 5.0.96
-- PHP Version: 5.1.6

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

--
-- Database: `t0tors102938`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `zip_codes`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `zip_codes`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zip_codes` (
  `zip_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `zip` varchar(5) NOT NULL default '',
  `abbr_state` char(2) NOT NULL default '',
  `lat` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  `lon` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  `city` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `full_state` varchar(50) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`zip_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `zip` (`zip`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=42523 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `zip_codes`
--

INSERT INTO `zip_codes` VALUES(1, '501', 'NY', '40.81', '-73.04', 'Holtsville', 'NY');
INSERT INTO `zip_codes` VALUES(2, '544', 'NY', '40.81', '-73.04', 'Holtsville', 'NY');
INSERT INTO `zip_codes` VALUES(3, '601', 'PR', '18.16', '-66.72', 'Adjuntas', 'PR');
INSERT INTO `zip_codes` VALUES(4, '602', 'PR', '18.38', '-67.18', 'Aguada', 'PR');
INSERT INTO `zip_codes` VALUES(20, '631', 'PR', '18.19', '-66.82', 'Castaner', 'PR');
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if you can use an array in a SELECT query, but I don't believe you can directly query the database with an array, but you could loop through a zipcode array and query the database with each zipcode:

```
$zips = array( '41240', '41256', '41202' );
$result = array();

foreach( $zips as $key=>$value ) {

     // Select query with $value
     // Save result to $result[ $key ]

}
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $result, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

→ Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to pass an array to the SQL query:

```
<?php
  $zipcodes  =  $_REQUEST["zipcode"];
  if( valid_zipcodes($zipcodes) ) // validate the data before query
  {
     $zipcodes  =  str_replace(
        array(']','['), 
        array(')','('), 
        json_encode($zipcodes) );
     mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_testimonials WHERE postcode IN $zipcodes;");
     // any other job
  }
?>
```

Your query will be like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_testimonials 
WHERE postcode IN ('123456', '987654');
```

Comment: Looking at my code how can i when the user searches all zip coded go into a single dimensional array cause right now zip codes are in $row[zip_code]

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this is using an SQL join with your 2 tables
The tables below are used to find tutors within a given radius using the [**Haversine**](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula in a SQL query using PDO

[image: tables]

```
// Prepare statement
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `tutors`.`name`, `tutors`.`zip`,`uszips`.`city`,`uszips`.`latitude`,`uszips`.`longitude`,( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( `uszips`.`latitude` ) ) * cos( radians( `uszips`.`longitude` ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( `uszips`.`latitude`) ) ) )  AS distance  FROM `uszips`, `tutors`  WHERE (`uszips`.`zip` =`tutors`.`zip`) HAVING distance < ?  ORDER BY distance ");
// Assign parameters
$stmt->bindParam(1,$center_lat);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$center_lng);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$center_lat);
$stmt->bindParam(4,$radius);
//Execute query
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['city'].",".$row['zip'].",".$row['name'].",".$row['distance'].",".$row['latitude'].",".$row['longitude'];
}
```

Where `$center_lat` and `$center_lng` are the coordinates of user and `$radius` is distance in miles.